# Android adapter unable to update

Tags: android, android-listview

I have an adapter and I want to add data to adapter.This is my source code:

```
private static class Random{
    public  JsonObject randomData=null;
    public  Integer badgeNumber=null;

    private Random(JsonObject randomData,Integer badgeNumber) {
        this.randomData=randomData;
        this.badgeNumber=badgeNumber;
    }
}

private static class Randoms{
    private List<Random> randoms=null;

    public Randoms(List<Random> randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
    }
    public Random get(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    public int size() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
}
private static class RandomsAdapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private Randoms randoms;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private RandomsAdapter(Context context,Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    public void updateRandoms(Randoms randoms) {
        this.randoms=randoms;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return randoms.size();
    }
    @Override
    public Random getItem(int position) {
        return randoms.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        View view=convertView;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.random_bars,parent,false);
        }
        Random item=getItem(position);
        Log.w("testt",""+item);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

And I am defining the adapter with this code:

```
Randoms randoms=new Randoms(randomsList);
randomsAdapter=new RandomsAdapter(this,randoms);
listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
listView.setAdapter(randomsAdapter);
```

When I try to add a data I am using this line

```
randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),1));
```

But this not working,I can't see any log with "testt" tag.How can I resolve this ?

I mean `getView` method is not working.

Comment: where you are calling `RandomsAdapter.updateRandoms(randomsList)` ?

Comment: When I call this method I am getting :The method updateRandoms(MainActivity.Randoms) in the type MainActivity.RandomsAdapter is not applicable for the arguments (List<MainActivity.Random>)

Comment: Ok,try as `Randoms randoms=new Randoms(randomsList);RandomsAdapter.updateRandoms(randoms)`

Comment: what is randomsList, where do you declare it?

Answer (score 0):

after adding

```
randomsList.add(new Random(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject(),1));
```

call notifyDataSetChanged() on your adapter

```
randomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Edit

```
((RandomsAdapter) randomsAdapter)notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: I am getting this error:The method notifyDataSetChanged() is undefined for the type ListAdapter

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by others, use

`randomsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

If you get an error like "`notifyDataSetChanged()` is undefined for the type `ListAdapter`", I guess it's because you're getting your adapter through `getAdapter()` or such method which returns a `ListAdapter`. In this case, you should cast it to either `BaseAdapter` or `RandomsAdapter`. For instance,

```
((RandomsAdapter) randomsAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: The method getAdapter() is undefined for the type ListAdapter